# How to minimize surface adsorption by choice of material?

Tags: physical-chemistry, materials, equipment

I need to do buoyancy experiments in vapours consisting of organic molecules in air using a microbalance. This involves measuring the change in weight of a sealed glass sphere when exposed to the gas. The problem is that surface adsorption shows up as significant noise. Is glass the best material for this? What properties determines adsorption, and how can I minimize it?

I assume it is a function of surface energy. For example PVDF has an energy about 10x less than glass. However, does this simply mean that it is easier to get rid of the adsorbed molecules rather than limiting the quantity in the first place?

Comment: Well, PTFE has a surface energy several times less than glass, so experiment time...